# Insert or select and returning the key

Tags: postgresql

What is the easiest way to insert a row in a database and returning its id if that row doesn't exist, otherwise return the ID of that word?

```
 INSERT INTO mytable (name) 
 SELECT 'd' 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE name='d') 
 RETURNING id
```

This code works only if the row doesn't exist.

I either do that and then a SELECT, or try the INSERT with ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING and then a SELECT again.

Is there a better solution?